# move image on relative layout screen in Android

Tags: android, move

I want an image to move some distance each time the user answer correct question ,I have reltive layout in xml, but I didn't find any way to do this ..
Also I have some buttons in my layout and I want them to still fixed all the time .

Here is snippet of my xml file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    tools:context="com.example.lolomahmoud.haqqalshams.bored">



    <Button
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="Start"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
 <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="quran"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button4"
        android:onClick="quran"/>

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"

        android:text="char"
        android:id="@+id/button4"

        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button5" />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

And here is snippt of my java code :

```html
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bored);tomain = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        mm = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        tomain.setOnClickListener(bored.this);
}


------
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // check if the request code is same as what is passed  here it is 2
        if (requestCode == 2) {
            // fetch the message String
            String message = data.getStringExtra("MESSAGE");
            // Set the message string in textView
            mm.setText("Your Score is :" + score);
            if (message.equals("true")) {
                rectangle++;//for all true ans}
//here I want the movmet of the button 
}}
```

Comment: Are you trying to animate image on some event triggered? And by the way I don't see an `imageView` in your layout file.

Comment: Yes.
This is because I tried using the button ,to make it moving !

Comment: Please help me for this issue !!